# FlatMap array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array

Tags: laravel

Estoy probando algunos helpers de laravel y me doy cuenta de que o algo estoy haciendo mal o este no funciona, uso laravel 5.2

Este es mi código.

```
    public function coleccionArrayAlfanumerico()
    {
      $resultado = collect(['pepino','porche','ramon','camisa','japones','movil','aprende el arte del pnl','Pentium IV','pescaderia']);

      return $resultado;
    }

    public function coleccionArrayClaves()
    {
        $clave = collect(['fruta', 'coche', 'nombre','ropa', 'idioma', 'tecnologia','libro', 'ORDENADOR', 'establecimiento']);

        return $clave;
    }

 public function flatMap()
       {

         $claves = $this->coleccionArrayClaves();
         $valores = $this->coleccionArrayAlfanumerico();
         $combinados = $claves->combine($valores);

         $flatmappeado = $combinados->flatMap(function($values){
            return array_map('strtoupper',$values);
          });

         $resultado = $flatmappeado->all();
         dd($resultado);
       }
```

El error es:

> ```
> array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array
> ```

No entiendo muy bien por que, me he basado en el ejemplo de la documentación y he creado arrays manualmente para no tener que coger datos de la base de datos para evitar mayores problemas.

¿Alguna idea?

------------------------------EDITADO----------------------------

El resultado de "combinados" es

```
Collection {#252 ▼
  #items: array:9 [▼
    "fruta" => "pepino"
    "coche" => "porche"
    "nombre" => "ramon"
    "ropa" => "camisa"
    "idioma" => "japones"
    "tecnologia" => "movil"
    "libro" => "aprende el arte del pnl"
    "ORDENADOR" => "Pentium IV"
    "establecimiento" => "pescaderia"
  ]
}
```

Haciendo un dd($values) o un var_dump aqui

```
$flatmappeado = $combinados->flatMap(function($values){
          dd($values);
            return array_map('strtoupper',$values);
          });
```

Su resultado es "pepino", es decir el primer elemento del array.
Poniendo "$values" o poniendo "$valores" el resultado es el mismo, es decir "pepino".

Shaz, realmente llama la atención que si parece que estas llamando a flatmap dentro de si mismo, pero realmente estoy cogiendo el mismo ejemplo de la documentación, tal cual, por eso me extraña que no funcione.

Comment: ¿Podrías usar un `gettype($values)` o `var_dump($values)` antes del `return`? Lo siento, no uso laravel, aunque uso bastante PHP. Acabo de leer en la documentación que combine admite como parámetro otra colección, no es necesario que sea otro array como supuse.

Comment: tendrá algo que ver con $values != $valores ?

Comment: Hay algo que no entiendo, ¿estás llamando el método flatMap dentro de si mismo?

Comment: Modificado post inicial, debajo de EDITADO, esta lo nuevo

Answer (score 0):

1. La razón por la que te da el error es porque estas dando una cadena de texto a la función array_map como segundo argumento, array_map espera un array como segundo argumento. (figura 1)
2. La razón por la que $values es igual a la cadena 'pepino' es por que la variable $combinado es un array de cadenas y su primer valor es 'pepino'.

Conclusion: Para evitar el error tendrías que:

- a) asegurarte que $combinado sea un array de arrays
- b) aplicar la función strtoupper directamente a la variable $values (figura 2). Lo cual te devolvería como resultado un array exactamente igual a $combinados.

[image: Figura 1]
[image: Figura 2]

Comment: Hoja @Oscar. Bienvenido a [es.so] y gracias por tu aporte. ¿Podrías [edit] tu repuesta para agregar el código como texto? Pensemos en quienes ven la respuesta desde un dispositivo con pantalla chica, tienen problemas de vista, o simplemente quieren copiarlo para probarlo. En caso de que quieras marcar una parte, se pueden usar comentarios. Para formatear el texto como código, luego de pegarlo, se debe seleccionar completamente y hacer click en el botón `{  }`.